# Question about C# EvaluateAsync for a simple piece of Javascript (i think)

Tags: javascript, c#, playwright

I am studying Playwright for some weeks now for a new project and am at the point to get acquainted with the insertion (how I call it now) of JavaScript in the web page. My simple webpage to test this looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Working!</h1>
        <div id="MyMsg">Bla Bla</div>
    </body>
    <script>
    var bb = document.getElementById("MyMsg");
    bb.textContent = "BladieBla";
    </script> </html>
```

In my ignorance I assumed I could put that piece of `<script>` code straight into:

```cs
await page.EvaluateAsync (" var bb = document.getElementById("MyMsg");   bb.textContent = 'Another Piece Of Text'; " );
```

but no luck. The documentation explains a lot, but just could not figure it out. So any help or hint is welcome.

Comment: Your code worked for me. What are you getting?

Comment: Not at home right now.  Will be back soon....

Comment: @hardkoded Works okay for me now as well. In my small piece of code I missed a semicolon. :-(